# How I Can Composite PNG file with 2 area with imagemagick?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I have some file like :

[image]

[image]

As you seen, in this png image, 2 or 3 area are over together,
When i want to composite with :
( code is example and isn't for this image )

```
exec("convert  1.png  ".$newfile01." -geometry +208+225 -compose DstOver -composite ".$newfile02." -geometry +434+346 -compose DstOver -composite  ".$newfile03." -geometry +656+211 -compose DstOver -composite  ".$result_image);
```

after composite $newfile01 with png file, few of other transparent area will be withe.

Any help? (sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I think you are saying your transparent areas are ending up white, and not transparent, in the output image. Try adding `PNG32:` in front of the output filename, like this `convert in1.png ... -composite ... PNG32:outfile.png`

Comment: For example i have 1.png and 2.jpg and 3.jpg, imagemagick composite 1.png with 2.jpg and some area from another transparent area will be white, then imagemagick composite it with 3.jpg. my problem is this area is white over on the 3.jpg area. :)

Comment: It is not a problem of ImageMagick - JPEG files cannot support transparency. You can take a JPEG without transparency though, and convert white areas to be transparent then save as PNG which does support transparency. To do that, add `-transparent white` after your JPEG filename.

Comment: i mean after composite number 1, a little of other transparency area will be withe and when composite number2 is running, white area is over on the new area and imagefile 02 ...

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.
In fact when i resize or rotate image it will be with white background:

```
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -resize 325!x440! -rotate -5.9 '.$newfile01.'');
```

and best solution is $newfile1 in this example be PNG file with transparent background and code is:

```
-matte -background transparent
```

so :

```
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -resize 325!x440! -matte -background transparent -rotate -5.9 '.$newfile01.'');
```

in this case, you don't have any problem with two or more image over together.

best Regards.